# Difference between self-signed CA and self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm not clear on the difference between a CA key and a certificate.  Isn't a CA key simply a certificate?  Let me try and clarify with an example.

I have a client and a server.  I'm only trying to validate my connection to my server and not trying to establish trust to others so I don't care about signing with a real CA.

**Option 1:** Generate a self-signed CA (**ssCA**) and use that to sign a certificate (**C**).  I then install **ssCA** into the root keystore on my client and setup my server to use certificate **C**.

**Option 2:** Generate a self-signed certificate (**SSC**).  Install **SSC** into the root keystore on my client.  Setup my server to use certificate **SSC**.

The second option seems like a much simpler process.  Should that still work?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Both options are valid, option 2 is simpler.

Option 1 (setting up your own CA) is preferable when you need multiple certificates. In a company you might set up your own CA and install that CA's certificate in the root keystore of all clients. Those clients will then accept all certificates signed by your CA.

Option 2 (self-signing a certificate without a CA) is easier. If you just need a single certificate, then this is sufficient. Install it in the keystores of your clients and you are done. But when you need a second certificate, you need to install that again on all clients.

Here is a link with further information: [Creating Certificate Authorities and self-signed SSL certificates](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403100211/https://metabrot.rocho.org/jan/selfsign.html)

Comment: If a CA signs a cert, can I still just individually trust the generated cert (**C** in this case), knowing that I would just need to trust every cert generated, rather than the one cert that comes from the CA?

Comment: @ivandov Depends on the client. Usually that should be possible, but some browsers (hello Chrome!) cannot be convinced to trust leaf certificates anymore. You will still get an error message.

Answer (score 71):

First, about the distinction between key and certificate (regarding "CA key"), there are 3 pieces used when talking about public-key certificates (typically X.509): the public key, the private key and the certificate.
The public key and the private key form a pair. You can sign and decrypt with the private key, you can verify (a signature) and encrypt with the public key. The public key is intended to be distributed, whereas the private key is meant to be kept private.

A public-key certificate is the combination between a public key and various pieces of information (mostly regarding the identity of the owner of the key pair, whoever controls the private key), this combination being signed using the private key of the issuer of the certificate.
An X.509 certificate has a subject distinguished name and an issuer distinguished name. The issuer name is the subject name of the certificate of the entity issuing the certificate. Self-signed certificates are a special case where the issuer and the subject are the same.
By signing the content of a certificate (i.e. issuing the certificate), the issuer asserts its content, in particular, the binding between the key, the identity (the subject) and the various attributes (which may indicate intent or scope of usage for the certificate).

On top of this, the PKIX specification defines an extension (part of a given certificate) which indicates whether a certificate may be used as a CA certificate, that is, whether it can be used as an issuer for another certificate.

From this, you build a chain of certificates between the end-entity certificate (which is the one you want to verify, for a user or a server) and a CA certificate you trust. There may be intermediate CA certificates (issued by other CA certificates) between the end-entity certificate of your service and the CA certificate you trust. You don't strictly need a root CA at the top (a self-signed CA certificate), but it's often the case (you may choose to trust an intermediate CA certificate directly if you wish).

For your use case, if you generate a self-signed certificate for a specific service, whether it has the CA flag (basic constraints extension) doesn't really matter. You would need it to be a CA certificate to be able to issue other certificates (if you want to build your own PKI). If the certificate you generate for this service is a CA certificate, it shouldn't do any harm. What matters more is the way you can configure your client to trust that certificate for this particular server (browsers should let you make an explicit exception quite easily for example). If the configuration mechanism follows a PKI model (without using specific exceptions), since there won't be a need to build a chain (with just one certificate), you should be able to import the certificate directly as part of the trust anchors of your client, whether it's a CA certificate or not (but this may depend on the configuration mechanism of the client).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm going to give Helge the correct answer since it came sooner and was briefer.  However, this was good to know.

Comment: A compromised CA-Certificate would do much more damage (compromises every TLS connection from the clients which it trusts) whereas the specific certificate would only impact the usecase the certificate was issued for.

Comment: @MarcoKinski True. That's why you should add name constraints to your self-generated CA certificates. This way a compromised self-generated CA certificate's private key cannot be used to MITM your traffic to external services. (i.e. those not matching the name constraint)

Answer (score 10):

You can `openssl x509 -noout -text -in $YOUR_CERT` to see the differences between files contents:

In your self-signed CA, you can see：

```
    X509v3 extensions:                                                          
        X509v3 Basic Constraints:
            CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
```

And in your self-signed certificate, it's:

```
    X509v3 extensions:                                                          
        X509v3 Basic Constraints:
            CA:FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need more certificates (**C**), you need to create a self-signed CA (**ssCA**). 
If you need a single certificate, you can just create a self-signed certificate (**SSC**).
To trust the single certificate (**SSC**), you need to install **SSC** into the root keystore on your client.
To trust many certificates at once, you need to create a self-signed CA (**ssCA**), then install **ssCA** into the root keystore on your client.

Answer (score 0):

You must always have a root CA, the CA has a key that can be used to sign a lower level certificate and a root certificate that can be embedded in the accepted root certificates on the client and is used to verify the lower certificates to check they are valid. Self signed just means you are your own CA. Whenever creating a self signed certificate you create a ca, then sign a site cert with that CA.