# Programatically distinguishing between self-signed and CA-signed certificates - IIS Bindings

Tags: c#, iis, ssl

I understand [the difference between self-signed and CA-signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024393/difference-between-self-signed-ca-and-self-signed-certificate), but I need to know if there is a way to distinguish between the two when they are contained in IIS's bag of bindings.

**Scenario**

I have two https bindings set up for my site, one with `CA-signed cert, X` and one with `self-signed cert, Y`.

In code, I have access to the bindings, which is a `ConcurrentBag<Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding>` used by IIS. I want to be able to tell which certificate is the self-signed and which is CA-signed using some property of the object.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use the `CertificateHash` and `CertificateStore` properties of each (applicable) `Binding` to [find the appropriate certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) and compare the subject and authority key identifiers in the x509 Extensions of the certificate

Comment: It is not easy as self signed if properly configured (like adding to trusted authorities store) works just like a commercial one. But if you keep a white list of issuers, then in code you can easily distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Mathias from the comments:

> Use the **CertificateHash** and **CertificateStore** properties of each (applicable) Binding to find the appropriate certificate and compare the **subject** and **authority key identifiers in the x509 Extensions** of the certificate

Comment: You should accept this answer and close the discussion.