# create-react-app: how to use https instead of http?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use https on dev for the 'create-react-app' environment. I can't see anything about that in the README or quick googling. I just want either the https://localhost:3000 to work, or else https://localhost:3001.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Set `HTTPS=true` before you run the start command.

[Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)

The implementation uses the [HTTPS Environment Variable](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0b1d6365768ae3bd267b042b74bab249673f1a9f/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L17) to determine [which protocol](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0b1d6365768ae3bd267b042b74bab249673f1a9f/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L81) to use when starting the server.

Comment: I tried this. I'm on Windows 10 and ran:

HTTPS=true&&npm start

This did not seem to work. I got the following console message as usual: Compiled successfully!

You can now view x-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.2.4:3000/

Comment: seems like your suggestion has something to do with proxying calls to a secure API server? I know react-scripts just calls something like http-server. I might be able to figure it out by looking at the output

Comment: Did you just run `HTTPS=true&&npm start`, on windows you need `set HTTPS=true&&npm start`.

Comment: The HTTPS section of the documentation is after Proxy Configuration, but the same header level. They are separate features.

Comment: It doesn't call `http.server` by itself, it uses `webpack-dev-server` which uses `express`.

Comment: OK, it works now. Is there a script where i can add the HTTPS env without having to type it everytime.(And also be compatible for Mac as well as PC

Comment: On a unix system like Mac you can export it in your profile. There's an equivalent way to globally set environment variables on windows, but I'm not familiar with it. But, at the project level `dotenv` should be initialized before the start, so you can try adding `HTTPS=true` to your `.env.development`

Comment: @SteveBuzonas et al., has anyone figured out how to define your own cert? In Firefox I can't proceed on https://localhost due to a 'The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.' error.

Comment: @Sean you would need to fork `react-scripts` or `eject` in order to do that. You can use a predefined cert with `webpack-dev-server`, but the scripts just allow it to generate a cert. Why not just add an exception?

Comment: @Ringo A little late to the party, but [this shows how to set `PATH` for Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml). It's the same process for any environment variable, like `HTTPS` or `NODE_ENV` or what-have-you on Windows. You can also open Windows Explorer, right click *This PC*, select *Properties*, then *Advanced System Settings*, then click the *Environment Variables* button... & profit.

Comment: @Sean You can pass in custom certificates with the `SSL_CRT_FILE` and `SSL_KEY_FILE` env vars and CRA will use them instead of the default ones from webpack. To have HTTPS working on localhost without the warning, you can use mkcert to create your own Certificate Authority and generate certificates with it. It sounds more complicated than it is and [this video shows you how](https://youtu.be/neT7fmZ6sDE)

Comment: Make sure that `HTTPS=true` is in upper-case, lower-case `https=true` will not work.

Comment: A full cmd line for Windows: `set PORT=443&&set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=./certs/fullchain.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=./certs/privKey.pem&& npm start`

Answer (score 54):

You can edit your package.json scripts section to read:

`"scripts": {
        "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
        ...
     }`

or just run `set HTTPS=true&&npm start`

Just a sidenote, for me, making this change breaks hot reloading for some reason....

-- Note: OS === Windows 10 64-Bit

Comment: To get this working without having to type it out every time I also put it in my package.json but I had to omit the `set` and the `&&` for it to work on my iMac. so I just used `HTTPS=true react-scripts start`

Answer (score 47):

You can also create a file called .env in the root of your project, then write

```
HTTPS=true
```

After that, just run "npm start" as you usually do to start your app.

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration

Works **both on Linux and Windows**, unlike some other answers posted here.

Answer (score 25):

## Windows (cmd.exe)

```
set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

(Note: the lack of whitespace is intentional.)

## Windows (Powershell)

```
($env:HTTPS = "true") -and (npm start)
```

## Linux, macOS (Bash)

```
HTTPS=true npm start
```

**Note** that the server will use a self-signed certificate, so your web browser will almost definitely display a warning upon accessing the page.

## Custom SSL certificate

```
HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=<SSLCert.crt> SSL_KEY_FILE=<SSLCert.key> npm start
```

## Linux, macOS (Bash)

```
HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=<SSLCert.crt> SSL_KEY_FILE=<SSLCert.key> npm start
```

**To avoid doing it each time:** 
You can include in the npm start script like so:

```
{
  "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start"
}
```

Or you can create a **.env** file with **HTTPS=true**

Comment: Custom SSL Certificate in Windows: `set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=<SSLCert.crt>&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=<SSLCert.key>&&npm start`

Answer (score 21):

In Case of MAC/UNIX do

```
export HTTPS=true
npm start
```

Or simple one liner

```
export HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

Or update start script in package.json to

`"start": "export HTTPS=true&&PORT=3000 react-scripts start",`

you should be able to hit https.

Answer (score 15):

`set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start` in *scripts* > *start:* of package.json as shown below.

***"scripts"*** in *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

- Please don't leave any space in between the commands i.e, `HTTPS=true && npm start` won't work.

Refer it in official doc.
[Using HTTPS in Development](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-https-in-development)

> **(Note: the lack of whitespace is intentional.)**

Comment: this helped.  the script changed slightly so now it would be: "start": "set HTTPS=true&&node scripts/start.js",

Answer (score 7):

I think it is worth to mention to set `PORT=443`, default `HTTPS` standard port.
You can avoid to attach `:PORT` at the end of the address when browsing every time.

```sh
su
export HTTPS=true 
export PORT=443
export SSL_CRT_FILE=/PATH/TO/cert.pem     # recommended
export SSL_KEY_FILE=/PATH/TO/privkey.pem  # recommended
npm start
```

## Or

you can put them all in to `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true PORT=443 react-scripts start",
```

Then, without `export`ing:

```
su
npm start
```

Answer (score 7):

```
"scripts": {
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&set PORT=443&&react-scripts start",
........
}
```

In case you need to change the port and set it to https.

Comment: how make settings if one use win another mac?

Answer (score 6):

Add to file .env (or .env.local) line:
HTTPS=true

Answer (score 5):

Please use this in command prompt

```
 set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

Answer (score 4):

might need to Install self-signed CA chain on both server and browser.
[Difference between self-signed CA and self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024393/difference-between-self-signed-ca-and-self-signed-certificate)

Answer (score 4):

if it's still not working properly because of "your connection is not private" issues (in chrome), this worked for me just fine:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3441

In short:

1. First I exported certificate from chrome (view this).
2. Imported the certificate into Windows (using certmgr.msc).
3. Allowed chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost flag. 
   [How to allow insecure localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531347/localhost-blocked-on-chrome-with-privacy-error)

Comment: You can also add a hosts file entry and access it by dns name like a production app to get around that issue

Answer (score 4):

You can create a proxy.HTTPS->HTTP

Create a key and cert.

`openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert`

Create a file named proxyServer.js

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
let fs = require('fs');

httpProxy.createServer({
    target: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000
    },
    ssl: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert', 'utf8')
    }
  }).listen(3000);
```

From the terminal run

`node proxyServer.js`

Answer (score 3):

I`m using **Windows 10** and I had the same issue.
I realized that you need to:

1. Run **Command Prompt** with **Administrator Privileges**
2. Run on the terminal bash this command: **`set HTTPS=true&&npm start`**
3. You can also put this code into your *package.json* file under the **scripts** section like this:

   `"scripts": {
       "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
       (...)
    }`
4. Bonus: If you want to change the **PORT** use this command insted:

   **`set HTTPS=true&&set PORT=443&&react-scripts start`**

   Obs.: Pay attention to the blank spaces NOT left in between some characters.

You can browse this [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development) for more detais.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your package.json file and change the starting scripts for starting your **secures domain**. for example https

```
 {
  "name": "social-login",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
    "react-google-login": "^3.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    // update this line "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Windows environment add following lines to package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "set HTTPS=true&&set PORT=443&&react-scripts start"
  },
```

It will start development server with https and port 443. 
At the present moment NodeJs have known bug to run this correctly but it worked with nodeJs v8.11.3 - https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-x64.msi for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, try this one

```
($env:HTTPS = "true") -and (npm start)
```

I am using VS Code Terminal (powershell).

Comment: Thanks, the fastest and easiest solution I was looking for, to test locally

Answer (score 1):

```
HTTPS=true npm start
```

in the terminal worked for me on Create-React-App

Comment: I get this error : 

The term 'HTTPS=true' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.

Comment: @NewtonSheikh I get the same error, what is the problem ?

Comment: @TaouBen from where are you executing? make sure u use cmd and not powershell ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898943/set-https-in-environmental-variable

Answer (score 1):

I could not get that to work (setting HTTPS=true), instead, i used

> react-https-redirect

A simple wrapper around your `App` component.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Windows 10** latest build with Windows Insider Program till this date.

It seems like there are three cases while using Windows 10:

1. Windows 10 with CMD command line for your NPM

```
set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

2. Windows 10 with PowerShell command line for your NPM

```
set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

3. Windows 10 with Linux Bash command line for your NPM ( My Case was this )

```
HTTPS=true npm start
```

Documentation: [Create react app dev](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/)

Comment: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Answer (score 1):

To avoid untrusted certificate errors in Chrome and Safari you should manually specify a self-signed key pair. CRA [allows you to specify them](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/#custom-ssl-certificate).

Also, use `.env` file to store these vars.

On macOS, just add your certificate to Keychain Access and then set `Trust Always` in its details.

Answer (score 1):

Important point about this issue: if you are looking to use https on LAN (rather than localhost) then SSL certification is an issue because the IP is not static!

This is a nice read on the subject where they explore the option of doing it anyway: [SSL For Devices in Local Networks](https://serverfault.com/questions/1060268/ssl-for-devices-in-local-network)

Answer (score 1):

Open the package.json file and change the start script file like given below.

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

to

```
"start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
```

Restart your localhost and check the terminal you are probably able to see the local and on your network runs by HTTPS.

Comment: ```set HTTPS=true && npm start```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Next.js version 13.5.1^

It has an *experimental flag* for the localhost server to run over https.

You can add the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "next start --experimental-https -p 14009",
    ...
},
```

Now when you run `npm start`, follow the instructions and you will be able to access localhost using `https://`

Answer (score -1):

// add this line to android manifest to use http when releasing apk in react native

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```