# set HTTPS in environmental variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

How to run React with https in windows. I need to set both port as well as HTTPS.

[Offical Facebook documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-https-in-development). But it doesnt talk about setting both the port and HTTPS. hence looks like i am missing something

here is my code

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set PORT=3000 && HTTPS=true && react-scripts-ts start",
  "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
  "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
}
```

PROBLEM AND SOLUTION:

I was using vscode Powershell terminal: It wont work :( 
Had to execute the npm command in windows CMD ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webserver which will be run by [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) is only for development purposes. If you need a HTTPS version of the website, you can simply set the `HTTPS` environment variable to true before you execute the start script. (like as you did).

Also the port is adjustable by using the `PORT` environment variable (for http and https version).

It's not possible to run both versions (http and https) at the same time and it's not intended to be used as a production web server. For that please consider to use [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/) to serve your static assets which will be generated through `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your package.json file and change the starting scripts for starting your **secures domain**. for example https

```
 {
  "name": "social-login",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
    "react-google-login": "^3.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",//updated line
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: na the problem was that i had to execute it from cmd and not from powershell. Powershell was the culprit. thanks anyways :)