# My react app stopped working when I set my HTTPS to true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, facebook-login

I am trying to Log in with Facebook in my react app, So I imported react-facebook-login and add FacebookLogin component to my app, I get an error on my console now saying this :

> The method FB.getLoginStatus can no longer be called from http pages.

So tho solve such problem, I tried to set my HTTPS to true, and I followed [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development) and typed :

> set HTTPS=true&&npm start

But I got an error telling me in french that  :

> Le jeton « && » n’est pas un séparateur d’instruction valide.

Which means that && is not considered as a valid separator of instruction.

So I tried others solutions to set my HTTPS to true, I went to package.json and made some changes :

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
        ...
     }
```

And started my application, but it is not working, localhost is not sending any response.

So how can I solve this ? and why I am getting those errors anyway ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I take it you're running on Windows?

Comment: yes, on Windows

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574399/create-react-app-how-to-use-https-instead-of-http

Comment: @Nemer I tried every possible answer in that question and nothing seems to work!

Comment: Have you tried `HTTPS=true react-scripts start` as your start script?