# create-react-app: how to use https but with signed cert?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, create-react-app

I've seen the quite useful answer here: [create-react-app: how to use https instead of http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574399/create-react-app-how-to-use-https-instead-of-http)

BUT

I'm not sure of the details on how to get this to work with a properly signed SSL cert.

Which version/format of the cert should I be using? PEM, or DER

I've seen some mention that you need to somehow combine the `Issuing CA.cer` and `Root CA.cer` (which I also have) into the PEM file. Is this correct?

Also, I'm using `yarn` and not `npm`, trying to use the following:

`HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=QA_SSL_Cert.cer SSL_KEY_FILE=server.key yarn react-scripts start`

The server starts, but I get the `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error when I try to connect. (Without enabling `HTTPS=true` the app itself runs just fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially correct. It seems that you are missing your chain of trust (probably because you haven't combined the `Issuing CA.cer` and `Root CA.cer`).

What you need to do is take the text from your signed SSL certificate, and append `Issuing CA.cer` and `Root CA.cer`, in that order, to the bottom.

Example (Chain certificate):

`My SSL Certificate`

`Intermediate SSL Certificate (Issuing CA)`

`Root SSL Certificate (Root CA)`

Each of the lines should be one after the other on separate lines (no empty lines between them).