# create-react-app https localhost Secure Connection Failed

Tags: https, openssl, create-react-app

I'm trying to use https on local dev for a 'create-react-app'.
I used this site as a tutorial for creating the certificate and got windows to trust it: https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-get-https-working-in-windows-10-localhost-dev-environment/

This is my .env file.

```
SSL_CRT_FILE=client-1.local.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=client-1.local.key
HTTPS=true
```

And this is my package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

After, I use the

> npm start

command, and go to https://localhost:3000/

- On Firefox I receive a

> Secure Connection Failed" error with very few details "An error
> occurred during a connection to localhost:3000.PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

- On Chrome I receive

> The connection was reset

I also checked this post [create-react-app: how to use https instead of http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574399/create-react-app-how-to-use-https-instead-of-http) but i didn't see anything that could have helped me.
I have windows 10.

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: make sure you are running the right command "npm run start:env", secondly have you tried "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=cert.key npm start
" ?

Comment: i tried both "npm start" and "npm run start:env". No difference. I removed the "start:env" from the "package.json" since this should work with "npm start" by default. I also tried to add the certificate file and key in the "package.json" insead of having them inside an ".env" file. Since i use windows (i updated also the question because i forgot about this) the command was a bit different : "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=client-1.local.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=client-1.local.key&&react-scripts start". But even so, no difference in the result

Comment: I added them also directly in the command as "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=client-1.local.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=client-1.local.key&&npm start". But still same result

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Edge. and here's how I solved it,

1. In edge browser type URL:- [edge://net-internals/#hsts](https://edge://net-internals/#hsts)
2. on "Delete domain security policies" enter "localhost" and press "delete".
3. Reopen [localhost:3000/](https://localhost:3000/)

*chrome also have a similar link [chrome://net-internals/#hsts](https://chrome://net-internals/#hsts)

Answer (score 1):

following the solution in the official [create-react-app website](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/) you should run :

```
set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

this will run "npm start" for you and the browsers should allow you to view the page