# react-create-app - can't access page via localhost - ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have problem with react-create-app, I can't access page via http://localhost:3000 when I try to run chrome/firefox on this address I'm redirected to https and I see ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error, but everything is working fine when I'm using ip like http://192.168.1.30:3000/ - I'm not auto redirected to https, and app is working fine.

Also I notice that when I'll desible cache in devtools, refresh page and go to http://localhost:3000 there will be no auto redirect and it will work until I close browser - but it's workaround not permanent solution.

Me env:

- node: v14.16.0
- npm: 6.14.11

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574399/create-react-app-how-to-use-https-instead-of-http

Comment: sure, I can use https but it's not solving my issue, that every new app will required to use https

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and clearing my cache in dev tools solved it. I was already running through https though so I'm not sure if that changes anything