# React Native and httpS with axios / heroku api

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

How does HTTPS work with react native after deploying?

I would deploy my Node/Express API Server to Heroku.
From there I get the SSL Certificate automatically.

But do I have to do something on the client side (React Native App) that the connection uses the httpS protocol?
(encrypted data traffic?)

Here is my Old Post, but nobody answered..

[React Native - Authentication - Prevent Token / Cookie being stolen / sniffed? #man in the middl #encrypt data? SSL / HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790030/react-native-authentication-prevent-token-cookie-being-stolen-sniffed)

Comment: Ideally, your server would redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS endpoints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574399/create-react-app-how-to-use-https-instead-of-http

Comment: @drnugent thanks for the quick answer. It was't really what I was looking for, but helped a to figure it mostly out on my own. Thanks 